# limit to only posts that are tagged using PHP

Tags: php, api, xpath, simplexml, tumblr

I am trying to only get the posts that are tagged on a tumblr blog. I can get each post depending on what type of post it is (regular, link, photo, etc) but instead, I want to get each post that has a certain tag on it. For example, only get the posts that are tagged 'file'

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://stocklamp.tumblr.com/api/read');
    $posts = $xml->xpath("/tumblr/posts/post[@type='photo']");
    foreach($posts as $post) {  

        }
    ?>

    <ul>
        <li> <a href="<?php echo $post['url-with-slug']; ?>">Post 1(PHP should be here)</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and here is tumblrs API http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll need to have your markup within the curly braces that belong to the `foreach` loop. Otherwise, the scope of the `$post` object you're referencing will not be available, and it give you an error.

This is what I came up with:

```
<ul>
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://stocklamp.tumblr.com/api/read');
$posts = $xml->xpath("/tumblr/posts/post/tag/..");
foreach($posts as $post) {
    echo "
  <li>
   <a href='{$post['url-with-slug']}'>".($post->{'regular-title'}?$post->{'regular-title'}:$post->{'link-text'})."</a>
  </li>
";
}

?>
</ul>
```

And if you want to limit the tags matched, you can do the following:

```
<ul>
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://stocklamp.tumblr.com/api/read');
$posts = $xml->xpath("/tumblr/posts/post/tag[contains(text(),'xml') or contains(text(),'php') or contains(text(),'firefox')]/..");
foreach($posts as $post) {
    echo "
  <li>
   <a href='{$post['url-with-slug']}'>".($post->{'regular-title'}?$post->{'regular-title'}:$post->{'link-text'})."</a>
  </li>
";
}

?>
</ul>
```

Of course, that's a little messy. I'm not necessarily an XPath guru, so there should be a cleaner way than that I would think.

And since I wasn't really digging on the ternary for the link text, or the fact I don't know if one or the other will always be available, this should be more descriptive with a fallback to the url.

```
<ul>
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://stocklamp.tumblr.com/api/read');
$posts = $xml->xpath("/tumblr/posts/post/tag[contains(text(),'xml') or contains(text(),'php') or contains(text(),'firefox')]/..");
foreach($posts as $post) {
    if ($post->{'regular-title'}) {
        $slug = $post->{'regular-title'};
    } else if ($post->{'link-text'}) {
        $slug = $post->{'link-text'};
    } else {
        $slug = $post['url-with-slug'];
    }
    echo "
  <li>
   <a href='{$post['url-with-slug']}'>".$slug."</a>
  </li>
";
}

?>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

And, you also might want to make a match of the entire text of the `TAG` element, so that you don't get matches on things like `xml-is-for-noobs` when you want `xml` tags only. `contains()` will match both, while the below will only match `xml`.

```
/tumblr/posts/post/tag[text() = 'xml']/..
```

So, according to your comment, if you're looking for posts tagged `events` but don't want to catch tags like `bowling-events`, `prevents fun`, `other events`, etc..., you would want to make the `text() = 'events'` match. On the other hand, if you DID want to match anything with `events` in the text of the `TAG` node, use the `contains(text(), 'events')` method.

**EDIT 2**

And if you're trying to limit the results, use `position()`:

```
(/tumblr/posts/post/tag[text() = 'xml']/..)[position() <= 3]
```

Note, the example on my webpage does not include the `text()` match, since there are not enough entries to support a submatch and still be productive. However, that should work.

http://jfcoder.com/test/tumblrtest.php

The XPath selects all `TAG` elements that belong to a `POST` element, then selects the parent (`..`) of that `TAG`, which gives you a SimpleXML object containing the relevant `POST` elements you're looking for.

Then, it iterates over each element, printing the `$post`'s information into a `UL` element.

Comment: I'm kinda understanding how this works now. But I don't see how you can change what tags should the post come up? Because for my client, I need to get all posts that are tagged 'events'.... for example I used to get all posts that are tagged file...

Comment: That's the `contains()` part. From what it sounds like, you would have one contains statements that was `/tumblr/posts/post/tag[contains(text(),'events')]/..`.

Comment: Oops, in the above comment I forgot the trailing `/..` to select the parent (which I fixed).

Comment: See my last edit about full text matching versus subtext matching.

Comment: I want anything thats tagged with 'events', even if it has other tags. This is nice. I will over read it and see if I can do this, if not I will comment. thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that each textual tag is in it's own `TAG` element. In other words, you'll be matching by the tag, not by a string that contains all tags. Thought I would mention this.

Comment: How can I limit only 5 list posts show up? I guess that can be done with CSS though.

Comment: Ohhhh haha! I DID IT! Thankkkk you! and I just use CSS to limit the posts huh

Comment: You can add an incrementing value with PHP (`$i++`), or use XPath `position()` (or use CSS, as you note). See my edit.